# How to save a file from an https link to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I would like to save a large file (approximately 50 GB) directly on Google Cloud storage. I tried `gsutil cp https://archive.org/download/archiveteam-twitter-stream-2015-08/archiveteam-twitter-stream-2015-08.tar gs://my/folder`, but that didn't work (`InvalidUrlError: Unrecognized scheme "https"`).

Is there a way of doing that, without having to first download the file to my local storage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use curl to fetch the URL and pipe it to gsutil. For example:

```
curl -L https://archive.org/download/archiveteam-twitter-stream-2015-08/archiveteam-twitter-stream-2015-08.tar | gsutil cp - gs://your/folder/archiveteam-twitter-stream-2015-08.tar
```

Comment: That still downloads it through my local, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. There's no way to have it copy through the cloud, unless you want to run the command on a GCE server.