# Transfer CSV To Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a csv hosted on a server which updates daily. I'd like to setup a transfer to load this into Google Cloud Storage so that I can then query it using BigQuery.

I'm looking at the transfer service and it doesn't seem to have what I need e.g. only accepts csvs or files from other google storage buckets or amazon s3 buckets.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a URL to a TSV file as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-manage-transfer-console#configure) and configure the transfer to run daily at the time of your choice.

Alternatively, if it still doesn't fit your need, you may install gsutil on your remote machine and use the `gsutil rsync` [command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) and schedule it to run daily.

Comment: thanks - for the URL list I don't know how to check the size (the csv changes daily) or how to create the hash. I tried using gstuil with this command: gsutil rsync -d -r gs://examplebucket http://example.com/my.csv but go the following error: Unrecognized scheme "http".

Comment: You can find more info at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48810888/4926605 on how to generate the hash. But since it changes every day and you have to submit the TSV file manually via the console, this may not be the best solution for you.

Comment: Regarding gsutil, you cannot reference a URL as source, it has to be local data. So you'd need to install gsutil on the server where your file is located and run the command from there.

Comment: Also, since you'd need to run the gsutil command on your server, you may be interested instead in loading the data into Bigquery directly as explained here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source

Comment: Looks like I found a fix to do it once here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209698/how-to-save-a-file-from-an-https-link-to-google-cloud-storage but now I'm stuck on scheduling. Do you have any knowledge on that?

Comment: Nice one. I hadn't thought about that. Regarding scheduling now, since it's basically a CLI command running on your machine, defining a cron job to trigger it will depend on your operating system. For Ubuntu for example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: I actually did it in the google cloud terminal but would the same command work on a local terminal?

Comment: Sure. You just need to install gsutil on your machine (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install)